# Filtrar en tabla sql en tiempo real con php

Tags: php, bootstrap

Buenas noches, mi duda es la siguiente.
Estoy haciendo una pagina de usuarios para un sistema de multas y ya tengo hecha mi conexión a base de datos, la cuestión es que me muestra la tabla de usuarios completa pero **quisiera agregarle a esa vista, la posibilidad de buscar en tiempo real,** es decir que me vaya filtrando de ese resultado a medida que yo voy tipeando letras.

Saludos!!

Maria

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Plantearé  un ejemplo de como hacer *(luego lo adaptas a tu sitio)*

haremos uso del evento [keyup](https://api.jquery.com/keyup/) (JQuery)  que se lanzará cuando el usuario suelte una tecla dentro del `input con id entradafilter`,

Posteriormente creamos un Objeto de Expresión Regular haciendo uso de [RegExp](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) como parámetros le enviamos el valor del input y una `i` que significa **(no distinguirá entre mayúsculas y mínusculas)**

Ocultamos todas las filas de la tabla con el efecto [hide](http://api.jquery.com/hide/) *(ocultar)* , Filtramos las filas con [filter](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) utilizando el Objeto de Expresión regular creada anteriormente. para finalmente mostrar dicha fila mediante el efecto [show](http://api.jquery.com/show/).

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
   $('#entradafilter').keyup(function () {
      var rex = new RegExp($(this).val(), 'i');
        $('.contenidobusqueda tr').hide();
        $('.contenidobusqueda tr').filter(function () {
            return rex.test($(this).text());
        }).show();

        })

});
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div class="input-group"> <span class="input-group-addon">Filtrado</span>
    <input id="entradafilter" type="text" class="form-control">
</div>
<table class="table table-striped">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>CODIGO</th>
            <th>NOMBRE</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody class="contenidobusqueda">
        <tr>
            <td>123456</td>
            <td>Felipe</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>987654</td>
            <td>María</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>565424</td>
            <td>Pedro</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>112322</td>
            <td>Milagros</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Disculpame, pero no entiendo que hago con el primer codigo debo hacerlo en un documento aparte y guardarlo?

Comment: Sólo es una división entre el html y el javascript, si lo separas o no es cuestión de tus necesidades, prueba buscando datatables.net quizá te sean de utilidad.

Comment: Genios absolutos! me funciono a la perfeccion!

Comment: Muy buena @Dev.Joel, +1. Lo que sí, agregaría un `try catch` para no llenar la consola de errores mientras se escribe una expresión regular, que podría momentáneamente tener un error de sintaxis. Por ejemplo, al tipear `^[a-z]+$`, tendrías 5 errores en consola.

Comment: eres un dios no sabes cuanto tiempo llevo haciéndolo y no me salia muchas gracias te vas a ir al cielo